# Hierarchical Tags in Google App Engine ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tags, app-engine-ndb

I'd like to have a simple, Ontology-style, tagging system for a product database in Google App Engine.

As a basic example, the tags would be pre-defined:

```
root
--Household
----Bedroom
------Bed
--------Sheets
--------Pillows
----Bathroom
------Bath
------Shower
```

For product tagged with `Sheets`, I would expect a search for the `Bedroom` tag to return that product. And I would want to ensure that when a product is tagged, only valid tags are entered.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```py
class HierarchicalTag(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    parent = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True, kind='HierarchicalTag')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How deep would the hierarchy go? Is it predefined?

Comment: Depth is arbitrary, but only defined once... Maybe I should just do it with a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hierarchy is only defined once I'd define a dictionary (or structure of your choice) of the hierarchy.
When creating a product, I'd save the path of tags against the product.

The model would look something like this:

```
class Product(ndb.model):
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

e.g. Using your example hierarchy, if saving a pillow I'd include: Household, Bedroom, Bed, Pillows.

```
Product(tags=['Household', 'Bedroom', 'Bed', 'Pillows'], name='Best pillow case')
```

Querying is then easy for any level in the hierarchy. e.g. querying bed products:

```
qry = Product.query(Product.tags=='Bed')
```

Or querying only for pillows:

```
qry = Product.query(Product.tags=='Pillows')
```

Comment: So given "Household" as a user entered tag (I won't be entering the product into the database), I could implement a simple depth-first-search to grab all of the tags in the subtree, then commit the result to the datastore... Awesome :) Thanks!